# Reading a file as stream using full path or classpath

Tags: java, file

I have a method `getMyFilePath()` which can return path to a directory as a `String`.

It can either return a classpath: `\com\mypackage\configdir\`
or 
it can return the fullpath: `C:\configdir\`

I want to modify below code so that it can handle both the cases above:

```
public void myMethod() {
   String myConfigDirPath = getMyFilePath();
   File configFile = new File(myConfigDirPath + "myConfig.txt");
   try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(configFile)) {
     // do something
   } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

`myMethod()` runs fine when the path is full i.e. `C:\configdir\` but gives the following error on `InputStream` line when the path is the classpath i.e. `\com\mypackage\configdir\`:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \com\mypackage\configdir\myConfig.txt 
(The system cannot find the path specified)
```

How do I modify `myMethod()` so that it works for both types of path?

Comment: Please provide your `getMyFilePath()` method

Comment: @tomrlh: How will that make any difference? Based on some logic, it either returns system path or classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the term “classpath” incorrectly.  A classpath is a list of directories and/or jar files, used to resolve classes and resources at runtime or when compiling.

The proper term for `\com\mypackage\configdir\myConfig.txt` is a *resource.*  It may be a file while it’s in your source tree, but if you ever try to package your program as a jar file, it will be inside the jar archive and will not be a file at all, so you cannot read it with FileInputStream.

A resource is read with the [getResourceAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) method, which is specifically designed to retrieve static data bundled with an application:

```
File configFile = new File(myConfigDirPath + "myConfig.txt");
try (InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(
    configFile.exists()
        ? new FileInputStream(configFile)
        : MyApplication.class.getResourceAsStream(
            configFile.toString().replace('\\', '/')))) {

    // do something
}
```

It can be made a little clearer by moving your configuration reading logic to a separate private method:

```
File configFile = new File(myConfigDirPath + "myConfig.txt");
if (configFile.exists()) {
    try (InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(
        new FileInputStream(configFile))) {

        readConfigurationFrom(is);
    }
} else {
    String configResourcePath =
        configFile.toString().replace('\\', '/')))) {
    InputStream configResource =
        MyApplication.class.getResourceAsStream(configResourcePath);

    if (configResource == null) {
        throw new ConfigurationException(
            "Cannot find the file \"" + configFile + "\""
            + " or the resource \"" + configResourcePath + "\"");
    }

    try (InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(configResource)) {
        readConfigurationFrom(is);
    }
}
```

Some additional notes:

- A resource is specified as a relative URL, like `/com/mypackage/configdir/myConfig.txt`.  URLs *always* use forward slashes (`/`), on all platforms.
- You should always read a file or resource using a BufferedInputStream (or BufferedReader).  It is considerably faster than reading individual bytes directly from a file.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is in class path, then you can load the file from class path using

```
      ClassLoader classLoader = <YourClass>.class.getClassLoader();
      InputStream is = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("myConfig.txt");
```

You can put this in the Catch block or you can check if it is class path upfront and then call appropriately